# Spring.io error 404 in the official example

Tags: java, spring, http, web

Currently Im new to spring and I tried the example (https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) they have on their website. I think I followed all steps correctly, but with a httpget in postman I only get this response:

```
"timestamp": "2023-01-04T09:23:03.965+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/greeting"
```

Here is the Code:

Greeting.java:

```
package com.example.restservice;

public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

GreetingController.java:

```
    package com.example.restservice;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

and here is the build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on your application class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the linked github and saw, that they have a RestServiceApplication.java, which is never created in the tutorial. After I added that, everything works fine now :)